# ssi file cannot be found by html file in subdirectory

Tags: html, ssi, shtml

I'm trying to link to an ssi that's in the root folder from a html file that's in a sub directory. Is there a certain way to do this?

eg:

```
root/example.ssi
root/examplefolder/example.html
```

We've tried using

```
<!--#include file="nav.ssi"-->
<!--#include file="../nav.ssi"-->
<!--#include virtual="nav.ssi"-->
<!--#include virtual="../nav.ssi"-->
<!--#include file="./nav.ssi"-->
<!--#include virtual="./nav.ssi"-->
<!--#include file="myurl.com/nav.ssi"-->
<!--#include virtual="myurl.com/nav.ssi"-->
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, Apache requires there be a space after the quote and before -->

Try `<!--#include virtual="../nav.ssi" -->`

Also which method of SSI directives are you using? If you're using XBitHack then ensure that your file has +x permission. Otherwise check that you have an AddOutputFilter directive for your file extension.

Answer (score 0):

If your web host sets the root of your web application to `/`, use an absolute path such as

```
<!--#include virtual="/example.ssi"-->
```

Even if that line included in `root/examplefolder/example.html`, the lookup on the webserver will find it. The absolute path doesn't start in the current directory, but what the web server is configured to have as its root path.